# Would it violate the TOS to install a third party hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

> Is it a violation of apples terms of service to
>   replace the factory installed hard drive with a larger third party
>   one?

I understand that it is a violation of the terms of service to install OSX on non-apple hardware and I was wondering if installing a third party hard drive would be a violation. If so would I need to buy a first party hard drive directly from apple, or is it completely taboo to poke around inside an apple product?

Simply put can you replace the hard drive of an Apple laptop with a third party hard drive?

Comment: You are asking for legal advice here?  Isn't there a better place for that?  Or are you really asking for uninformed opinions: "should it be a violation of TOS"?

Comment: An uninformed opinion, I thought my lack of knowledge on this subject only came from my lack of experience with apple products and that people who use apple products regularly would have encountered this question commonly. I can't find anything even talking about it. I have seen tutorials on how to do it, but I can't find anything from apple saying a clear yes this is ok, or a clear no do not do it.

Answer (score 1):

Done all the time. Apple does not make drives, so really all drives are non-Apple hardware.

The TOS restriction is targeted at complete clones - main board, case etc.

Various Apple models over the years have considered the drives to be user-replaceable - they just slide out without any tools. The pre-cylinder Mac Pro and XServes are good examples. Various laptop models made the drive very easy to change - one screw and it pops right out.

Answer (score 0):

you will void your warranty unless you have a certified apple technician do it.
(many small tech shops are apple certified, not just apple store geniuses.)

Comment: disagree, completely. What about a Mac Pro with 6 SATA slots? Adding a second drive voids warranty? Try getting that one to hold up in court. Cracking a laptop open might be a different matter, but the sweeping statement is misleading.

Comment: this is not a legal debate, the original poster was asking if it was against the Terms of Service.